# SQL query related to highest salary finding

Tags: sql

The following query:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY sum(salary) DESC) as num,id, sum(salary) as salary
FROM person
GROUP BY id
where num=3;
```

is giving me an error at `where` condition and I want to get row 3 data... What would be the solution for this?

Comment: WHERE filters before the aggregation, you need HAVING which filters the results after the aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

You need a subquery:

```
select p.*
from (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sum(salary) DESC) as num, id,
             sum(salary) as salary
      from person 
      group by id
     ) p
where num = 3;
```

(Well, unless you are using Teradata and can use the `qualify` clause.)